# Magento 2.3.3 - import newsletter subscribers from CSV

Tags: php, magento2.3, import, newsletter, newsletter-subscriber

Running a multi website and store setup.

Example

Website - Japan
Store - JP
Store View - JP

I'm trying to import newsletter subscribers from a CSV.

I'm using the following code in a file called **import.php** that I run from the root dir. eg: dev.xyz.com/import.php and the subscribers.csv is also in the root dir.

```
<?php
  ob_start();
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$store_id = 1;
$csv_filepath = "subscribers.csv";
$csv_delimiter = ',';
$csv_enclosure = '"';
$magento_path = __DIR__;

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$websiteId =  $obj->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
    ->getStore()
    ->getWebsiteId();

$customerAccountManagement =$obj
    ->create('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');

$_subscriberFactory = $obj->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory');


if (($handle = fopen("subscribers-import.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // email Id
        $emailId = $data[1];
       /* customer */
        if($customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($emailId , $websiteId)){
            echo $emailId ."<br/>";
            $_subscriberFactory = $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId );
        }else{
            echo $emailId ."Register <br/>";
            $customerFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
            $customer=$customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($emailId );// load customer by email address
            if($customer->getId()){
                $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
            }

        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

CSV Headers/Column names as follows:

**ID | Email |  Type |  Customer First Name |   Customer Last Name |    Status |    Website Store | Store View**

But I get the following error

```
IDGuest

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/import.php:36) in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 148

Fatal error: Uncaught Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\FailureToSendException: The cookie with "mage-cache-sessid" cookieName couldn't be deleted. in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php:154 Stack trace: #0 /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php(301): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->setCookie('mage-cache-sess...', '', Array) #1 /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/Plugin/SessionChecker.php(54): Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\PhpCookieManager->deleteCookie('mage-cache-sess...', Object(Magento\Framework\Stdlib\Cookie\CookieMetadata)) #2 /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(121): Magento\Customer\CustomerData\Plugin\SessionChecker->beforeStart(Object(Magento\Framework\Session\Generic\Interceptor)) #3 /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Sessio in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/framework/Stdlib/Cookie/PhpCookieManager.php on line 154
```

How can I import newsletter subscribers from a CSV?

Thanks in advance.

---

### UPDATE

Changed code as suggested by Rajesh Hothi

Now I get the following error

```
IDGuest

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: The input is not a valid email address. Use the basic format local-part@hostname in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php:501 Stack trace: #0 /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/import.php(37): Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber->subscribe('ID') #1 {main} thrown in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/vendor/magento/module-newsletter/Model/Subscriber.php on line 501
```

Format of CSV file shown below.

[image]

It uses comma ',' as seperator

- ID,Email,Type,Customer First Name,Customer Last
  Name,Status,Website,Store,Store View
- 1,lht@gmail.com,Customer,村瀬,康洋,Subscribed,Japan,JP,Japan
- 2,4337@icloud.com,Guest, ----, ----,Subscribed,Japan,JP,Japan
- 3,naka1222@gmail.com,Customer,TANAKA,MASAKI,Subscribed,Japan,JP,Japan
- 4,eshire@gmail.com,Customer,古賀,裕章,Subscribed,Japan,JP,Japan

It imports one line in which the email ID doesn't show and its not in the order of the csv file, as below.

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

Changed code as suggested by Raul Sanchez, it gave the same error, I figured it was the header row (row 1) that was causing error and removed it.

now it gives the following error

```
lht@gmail.com
4337@icloud.com

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on integer in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/import.php:37 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /home/xyz/dev.xyz.com/import.php on line 37
```

its not importing the subscriber names, type, nor the correct website, store or store view.

[image]

Comment: Email is the second column in csv file, so you should get it as $data[1]

Comment: have updated my question, based on your suggestion.

Comment: Try changing `$_subscriberFactory = $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId );` for just `$_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId);`

Comment: changed $_subscriberFactory = $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId ); for just $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId);  that imports the email ID but the Type | Customer First Name | Customer Last Name | Status | Website Store | Store View does not get imported.

Comment: Well, you should parse the csv data & send that info to update subscriber info... in your code it seems you are just getting the email `$emailId = $data[1];`

Comment: How would I go about getting the rest of the data imported?

Comment: Maybe you can ask a new question for this, so it is more clear (and clean) for community what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

1.Remove Whitespace before (start) `<?php` and after (end) `?>`

2.Put  `ob_start();` at top and   `ob_end_flush();` at end of the script

```
<?php
  ob_start();

  // code 

 ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: I get another error, have updated my question.

Comment: Please print  array echo  $data[1]; exit; and check what will it print ?

Comment: also check your csv file format is UTF-8 ?

Comment: it is UTF-8 created on Google sheets, and echo prints the first email ID

Comment: Please try with https://blog.mdnsolutions.com/magento-2-import-newsletter-subscriber-programmatically/